# How to limit how high the users number input is?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been looking on stack overflow but not found the answer that fits my program. I don't want the user to be able to put any number higher than 24 (due to only 24 hours in a day). I don't know whether input boxes are suitable or not. Any help will be awesome!

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
  <title>The Gaming Hours Quiz</title>
   <body>
    <h1>The Gaming Hours Quiz</h1>
   </body>
    <p>Welcome to the Gaming Hours Quiz. Please fill out the neccesary information correctly to get your true results</p>

  <h3 id= "nametitle">What is your name?</h3>
<input id="name" type="letter" name="" value="type name here..." />    

  <h3>How many hours have you gamed on Monday?</h3>
<input id="monday" type="number" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2" />


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Tuesday?</h3>
<input id="tuesday" type="number" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Wednesday?</h3>
<input id="wednesday" type="number" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Thursday?</h3>
<input id="thursday" type="number" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Friday?</h3>
<input id="friday" type="number" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Saturday?</h3>
<input id="saturday" type="number" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Sunday?</h3>
<input id="sunday" type="number" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>





<br>
<br>
<button id="button">Submit</button>


</html>
<script>

function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}


function total() {
 var th = Number(monday.value) + Number(tuesday.value) + Number(wednesday.value) + Number(thursday.value) + Number(friday.value) + Number(saturday.value) + Number(sunday.value);
 alert("You gamed for " + th + " hours this week");



var ah = th / 7;
alert("Your average is " + ah + " hours this week");

var arr = [Number(monday.value), Number(tuesday.value), Number(wednesday.value), Number(thursday.value), Number(friday.value), Number(saturday.value), Number(sunday.value)]

var hh = 0;
var max = arr[0];
var days = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];
var dayOfMax = 0;

for(var i = 1;i < arr.length;i++) {
 if(arr[i-1] < arr[i]) {
   max = arr[i];
    dayOfMax = i;
  }
}

alert("Maximum hours you have gamed in one day is " + max);
alert("The day when you have gamed the maximum amount on is " + days[dayOfMax]);
// 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, 2 for Wednesday, and so on
}


button.onclick = total;

</script>
```

Comment: Use dropdown, it will be better user experience

Comment: Just add `max="24"` to your `<input>`s. Restricting input values isn't a good practice and it doesn't give you any extra security.

Comment: This method does not work

Comment: @JamesL You have to understand that there is absolutely no way to *guarantee* the user doesn't try to enter any invalid number: just open up the console and voila they can put in anything they want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add max="24" or else do like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Modify the text in the input field, then click outside the field to fire the onchange event.</p>

Enter some text: <input type="number" id="numbertype" name="txt" value="" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">

<script>
function myFunction(val) {
     if(val > 24)
     {
      alert("Please enter less or Equal to: " + val)
       document.getElementById('numbertype').value =  24;
     }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

for ref https://plnkr.co/edit/2jnOzyrlgCeCi8ydatUg

Answer (score 0):

## `min` and `max` attributes

You should use the HTML5 input attributes `min` and `max`. Additionally, this adds browser validation to the input fields. See the code example for a fixed version of your example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
  <title>The Gaming Hours Quiz</title>
   <body>
    <h1>The Gaming Hours Quiz</h1>
   </body>
    <p>Welcome to the Gaming Hours Quiz. Please fill out the neccesary information correctly to get your true results</p>

  <h3 id= "nametitle">What is your name?</h3>
<input id="name" type="letter" name="" value="type name here..." />    

  <h3>How many hours have you gamed on Monday?</h3>
<input id="monday" type="number" min="0" max="24" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2" />


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Tuesday?</h3>
<input id="tuesday" type="number" min="0" max="24" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Wednesday?</h3>
<input id="wednesday" type="number" min="0" max="24" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Thursday?</h3>
<input id="thursday" type="number" min="0" max="24" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Friday?</h3>
<input id="friday" type="number" min="0" max="24" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Saturday?</h3>
<input id="saturday" type="number" min="0" max="24" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>


<h3>How many hours have you gamed on Sunday?</h3>
<input id="sunday" type="number" min="0" max="24" name="" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2"/>





<br>
<br>
<button id="button">Submit</button>


</html>
<script>

function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}


function total() {
 var th = Number(monday.value) + Number(tuesday.value) + Number(wednesday.value) + Number(thursday.value) + Number(friday.value) + Number(saturday.value) + Number(sunday.value);
 alert("You gamed for " + th + " hours this week");



var ah = th / 7;
alert("Your average is " + ah + " hours this week");

var arr = [Number(monday.value), Number(tuesday.value), Number(wednesday.value), Number(thursday.value), Number(friday.value), Number(saturday.value), Number(sunday.value)]

var hh = 0;
var max = arr[0];
var days = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];
var dayOfMax = 0;

for(var i = 1;i < arr.length;i++) {
 if(arr[i-1] < arr[i]) {
   max = arr[i];
    dayOfMax = i;
  }
}

alert("Maximum hours you have gamed in one day is " + max);
alert("The day when you have gamed the maximum amount on is " + days[dayOfMax]);
// 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, 2 for Wednesday, and so on
}


button.onclick = total;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Attribute max=24 and use onkeyup event

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    Enter Value: <input type="number" id="numbertype" name="txt" max="24" value="" onkeyup="check(this.value)">
    <script>
    function check(val) {
         if(val > 24)
           {
            alert("Please enter less or Equal to 24");
            document.getElementById('numbertype').value =  24;
             }

        }
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to identify whether user entering value greater than 24,

```
 $('#monday').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() >= 25) {
           alert("pls enter less value");                               
            $('#monday').val(''); //this will empty the textbox
        }
     });
```

Likewise you can use it for rest of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: insted of

```
 <h3 id= "nametitle">What is your name?</h3>
 <input id="name" type="letter" name="" value="type name here..." />
```

use

```
 <h3 id= "nametitle">What is your name?</h3>
 <input id="name" type="letter" name="" placeholder="type name here..." />
```

so that the user own't have to delete "type name here..."